# socket.gaierror while using aiohttp

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp, python-asyncio

I am trying to fetch titles from multiple domains.
So im wrote this code:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.70 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Encoding': ', '.join(('gzip', 'deflate', 'br')),
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
}


async def fetch(url, session):
    async with session.get(f'http://{url}') as response:
        text = await response.text()
        return url, BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml').title.string


async def main():
    async with asyncio.Semaphore(50):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=False), timeout=aiohttp.ClientTimeout(10),
                                         headers=headers) as session:
            titles = await asyncio.gather(*[fetch(domain, session) for domain in domains[0:500]],
                                          return_exceptions=True)
            for title in titles:
                print(title)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    domains = []
    with open('input', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            domains.append(line.rstrip())

    asyncio.run(main())
```

It works, but sometimes throw error like this

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-1635' coro=<TCPConnector._resolve_host() done, defined at /venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py:774> exception=gaierror(8, 'nodename nor servname provided, or not known')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 829, in _resolve_host
    addrs = await \
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/resolver.py", line 29, in resolve
    infos = await self._loop.getaddrinfo(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 817, in getaddrinfo
    return await self.run_in_executor(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 914, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-1617' coro=<TCPConnector._resolve_host() done, defined at /venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py:774> exception=gaierror(8, 'nodename nor servname provided, or not known')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 829, in _resolve_host
    addrs = await \
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/resolver.py", line 29, in resolve
    infos = await self._loop.getaddrinfo(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 817, in getaddrinfo
    return await self.run_in_executor(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 914, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Sometimes it throw more errors, sometimes less.
Can anyone explain why it throw it?
I tried to wrap get method in try: except: construction just like this, but it still not working.

```
async def fetch(url, session):
    async with session.get(f'http://{url}') as response:
        try:
            text = await response.text()
            return url, BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml').title.string
        except BaseException as e:
            return e
```

Comment: I don't know about "Task exception was never retrieved" part,but have some hint for `gaierror`: I had similar problems some time ago, when my DNS server got too many request in too short time. My app asking for *existing* domain entries resulted in similar errors. I've setup DNS cache between my app and the world, and this solve everything for me. Maybe search in this direction (i.e. tweak DNS resolver cache https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#tuning-the-dns-cache or connection pool size: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#limiting-connection-pool-size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a temporary fix (XREF: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/3549#issuecomment-1359137365), have you tried

```bash
ulimit -n unlimited
```

It can be made to persist in other ways, but this should work as a temporary (and per-shell) fix.

Try it!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Hope this this will help anyone who are facing this problem